# Can't find the right spot to paste my embedded CSS in Gmail

Tags: css, gmail, html-email

A few months ago I started doing some research on HTML emails (never done those before). I read that Gmail started to support embedded CSS or "block" CSS as of September, '16. Since that time I have been trying off and on to figure out how to get Gmail to render the embedded CSS when I receive my test msgs. They look fine when I am composing them. I used this YouTube video to learn how to insert the markup in the compose window:

https://youtu.be/QprIvjZ5TYI?t=2m44s

Replacing the entire div the way the video said didn't work, but I tried replacing just the dummy text itself and when I clicked back into the compose window, the css & html were rendered perfectly. Screencap below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDedl.jpg

Problem is when I sent it and looked at the incoming email, the style rules were ignored. Itried to post another screencap but SO is telling me I need reputation of 10 to do so and I'm a lowly 1. Anyway, trust me that all of the text on the incoming message was black.

In my first attempt I used the WHOLE html file, from .... Then I tried .... Same results. Then I tried expanding the DIVs I was replacing, replacing the parent DIV instead of the original, then its parent's DIV... That got me nowhere. Used both Firefox and Chrome, same on both. I'm out of ideas. It seems other people are getting embedded CSS to work. Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
- DK

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking if you're about to send HTML e-mails you should do that using some external mail software (like Microsoft Outlook, Mozilla Thunderbird, Apple Mail etc.) and send it via SMTP.

In your case it will work, if your styles are inline, so you can send something like:

```
<p style="color: blue">This is a blue text</p>
```

But there is no way of sending something like:

```
<p>This is a blue text<p>
```

And attaching external .css file, because you can't attach CSS files in e-mails this way.

You can always convert your CSS and HTML into HTML with inline CSS using some minifiers, like [here](https://www.myintervals.com/emogrifier.php) or [here](https://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/inline-css/) or [here](https://inliner.cm).

If you're 100% sure you're providing right HTML with inline CSS then you should **save your HTML e-mail as a draft** and then send it from your Drafts view. It works for me:

[image]

Unforunately you can't send HTML mails directly, but after saving it as a template / draft it will be processed by Gmail and then it should work as expected.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi Bart, thanks for the quick response. I know I can't use an external stylesheet. I am trying to do it using a style block <style>...</style> followed by the HTML content. The folks over at Litmus have been doing well with it. Link below:  https://litmus.com/blog/gmail-to-support-responsive-email-design

Comment: AFAIK it won't work like that in the browser, from the site you linked in your comment: http://i.imgur.com/TrTN9dd.png . You have to use some third party software to send your HTML e-mail or just go the "inline css" way using gmail.com.

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML file just add the `<style>` in a standard place within the `<head>` and it should work as expected.

Litmus did a really good write up of the Gmail responsive update, it's worth a read.
https://litmus.com/blog/gmail-to-support-responsive-email-design

Comment: Dont forget only the first style is supported by Gmail.

Answer (score 0):

As of October 2020, the Gmail UI  still doesn't allow to compose email messages using HTML / CSS.

Here is a summary of the the trick shown in the referred video:

1. Click the compose button of the Gmail Web UI
2. Add a dummy text
3. Select the dummy text the use the Chrome DevTools to edit the element holdin the dummy text.

Unfortunatelly this doesn't allow to include `<style>...</style>`. If you dedide to use an external editor you could use the standard HTML structure

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      p {
        color:Maroon;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
   <p>Hello worl!</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

One option is to use Google Apps Script to compose your HTML messages. While it doesn't offer WYSWYG you could create a simple web app and make it available only to you.

The following example use scriptlets to create and style a simple table (the use of scriptlets is optional).

Code.gs

```js
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index').evaluate()
}
```

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <style>
      body {
        background-color:gray;
      }
      table {
        margin:auto;
        
      }
      tr .header {
        background-color:navy;
        color:white;
      }
      tr .label {
        background-color:white;
      }
      tr .value{
        background-color:white;
        text-align:right;
      }
      tr .totals {
        background-color:white;
        color:navy;
        font-style:italic;
        text-align:right;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <? const headers = ['Fruit','Qty'];?>
      <? const data = [
        ['Apple',5],
        ['Banana',10],
        ['Cherry',20]
      ];?>
      <colgroup>
        <col span="1" style="width:100px">
        <col span="1" style="width:50px">
      </colgroup>
      <thead>
        <tr >
          <? for (var header of headers) {?>
          <th class="header"><?= header ?></th>
          <?}?>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <? for(var row of data){ ?>
        <tr >
          <td class="label"><?= row[0] ?></td>
          <td class="value"><?= row[1] ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?}?>
      </tbody>
      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <td class="totals">Totals:</td>
          <td class="totals"><?= data.reduce((total,row) => total + row[1],0)?></td>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

If you dont' wan to use scriplets on the Code.gs file instead of

```
HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index').evaluate()
```

you could use

```
HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index')
```

The above works fine when sending the email but doesn't work for messages that are saved as  draft, so if you need to save your messages as draf, instead of using `<style>...</style>` use inline styles.

Resources

- [Gmail Sender Resources > CSS Support](https://developers.google.com/gmail/design/css)
- [Composing draft messages](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/gmail/compose#example) (This explains how to create a Gmail add-on to compose a draft, but doesn't mention how to include CSS)

Related

- [How to paste raw HTML into an email in Gmail?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/3554/88163) (from Web Applications)